# Exported spreadsheet from rdlc contains extra rows

Tags: c#, rdlc

Original layout in RDLC file does has 0 points in between the textboxes. But every time I export it to excel it'll have a row between it. Any idea on how to avoid it or fix it?

Original rdlc layout
[image]

Exported excel
[image]

Comment: could be paper size or layouts issue.

Comment: Are you using the official `.NET Framework` Reporting Services or `.NET Core` / `.NET 5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already found a fix for this issue. This was caused by the 'Allow height to increase' in the textbox properties.